# How to write Socket data into text file in c#

Tags: c#, sockets, text-files

I have a code snippet which is reading data from ip address and port.Now as per my need i have to save this data into text file but i dont know how to do it ..

Here is my code ...

```
class Listener
{

    private TcpListener tcpListener;
    private Thread listenThread;
    // Set the TcpListener on port 8081.
    Int32 port = 8081;
    IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.3");
    Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];


    private void ListenForClients()
    {

        this.tcpListener.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            //blocks until a client has connected to the server
            TcpClient client = this.tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

            //create a thread to handle communication 
            //with connected client
            Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClientComm));
            clientThread.Start(client);
        }
    }
    private void HandleClientComm(object client)
    {
        TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
        NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

        byte[] message = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;

        while (true)
        {
            bytesRead = 0;

            try
            {
                //blocks until a client sends a message
                bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 4096);
            }
            catch
            {
                //a socket error has occured
                // System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("socket");
                break;
            }

            if (bytesRead == 0)
            {
                //the client has disconnected from the server
                // System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("disc");
                break;
            }

            //message has successfully been received
            ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();

            //Here i need to save the data into text file ...

        }

        tcpClient.Close();
    }
}
```

And my text file address is ...

```
D:\ipdata.txt
```

Please help me ..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Have you looked at the `FileStream` class?

Comment: Use `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` to convert bytes to text and vice versa, and `FileStream` to save it to file

Comment: possible duplicate of [Save file from a byte\[\] in C# NET 3.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733832/save-file-from-a-byte-in-c-sharp-net-3-5)

Comment: @CodeCaster String textdata = encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead);
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"D:\ipdata.txt", textdata);  will this be enough to save as text in text file..

Comment: Probably, why don't you try it? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `FileStream` using `File.Open()` or `File.OpenWrite()`:

```
using (Stream output = File.OpenWrite(@"D:\ipdata.txt"))
{
    // the while loop goes in here
}
```

You are hinting the use of `ASCIIEncoding`. Usually if you receive ASCII you don't need to decode the data - you could simply write the data to the file directly:

```
if (bytesRead == 0)
{
    break;
}
else
{
    output.Write(message, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

If some kind of decoding needs to take place, you may need to buffer the incoming data and either write the entire thing after the socket has disconnected, or write in batches. For example if you expect UTF-16, there is no guarantee that you receive an even number of bytes on each `Read()`.

PS none of the code is tested, it's supposed to be just an example.